# Python: List Comprehension for a 2D List

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, list-comprehension

This is my code currently:

```
data = [''.join(sorted(e)) for e in d.split() for d in data.splitlines()]
```

I am trying to convert:

```
'''zax xza admbc lvpzfeh auxn rwasj
kebx eild nrskdr meja jxczomh gcne'''
```

To:

```
[['axz','axz','abcdm','anux','ajrsw']['bekx','edil','dknrrs','aejm','cegn']]
```

I keep receiving the error:

```
data = [''.join(sorted(e)) for e in d.split() for d in data.splitlines()]
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

Any help is greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: You got the order of your `for...in` statements reversed.

Comment: You're also missing nesting a list, eg: `[[''.join(sorted(word)) for word in line.split()] for line in your_text.splitlines()]`... When in doubt - write something out fully as nested for loops and building a list, you then have a good starting block to un-nest it back to a list-comp. (Also - it does help using more meaingful names such as `word` or `line` which indicate the order of things, rather than `d` and `e`)

Comment: OK, I've got it working now, thank you for your feedback.